# Trying to move a sitecore Item into a folder in the content tree

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6

I've created a structure in Sitecore's content tree as follows :
A Home root item, based on a template. Then I have a series of folders under the Home item, named by dates.

I'm creating a command template so that when I add a new item under the Home item, it automatically moves it under the folder represented by the current date.

However, the Item class' `MoveTo` method only takes an Item as a parameter. So I have no idea how to tell it to move the Item into a Folder, as a Folder cannot be represented as an Item?

I've done some digging, and I've seen that when I place an item directly under the folder, it shows a different ParentID than if I put it directly under the Home item, implying that the Folder is indeed an Item. However, when I try to retrieve the Item represented by the Folder, I get null.

e.g. `Sitecore.Context.Database.Items["/sitecore/content/Home/30Nov2011"];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in Sitecore is an item (even folders), you can resolve the folder as an item based on its `path` or `GUID` using the `Database` object.

```
var currentDb = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master");
var folderItem = currentDb.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home/30Nov2011");
Sitecore.Context.Item.MoveTo(folderItem);
```

**Edit:** As you are working in the content editor environment you will need to explicitly tell it which database to use (the `master` database in this case) as the `Context` scope will not contain the database you are hoping to work with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep that did it. What's strange is that when I retreived the item for my Home item, it worked, but for the folder, it returned null. Surely if it didn't know which DB I was working it, it should have returned null for both? In any case, the code given here works. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You will probably find that the DB its connected to in the context scope (core or shell) also has a 'Home' item but the ID would be different to the 'Home' item in your 'master' db as it would be a completely different item.